# How do I make mutter use my nouveau GPU

Tags: nvidia, gnome-shell, nouveau, mutter

I am using a laptop which has a discrete nvidia GPU along with the Intel GPU.

```
$ inxi -G
Graphics:  Device-1: Intel HD Graphics 530 driver: i915 v: kernel 
           Device-2: NVIDIA GM107M [GeForce GTX 960M] driver: nouveau v: kernel 
           Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.8 driver: intel,nouveau resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz, 2560x1440~60Hz 
           OpenGL: renderer: NV117 v: 4.3 Mesa 20.1.7 - kisak-mesa PPA
```

with hybrid-graphics service active

```
$ sudo systemctl status switcheroo-control.service
● switcheroo-control.service - Switcheroo Control Proxy service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/switcheroo-control.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Fri 2020-09-11 19:28:59 PDT; 20h ago
   Main PID: 1267 (switcheroo-cont)
      Tasks: 3 (limit: 18985)
     Memory: 1.5M
     CGroup: /system.slice/switcheroo-control.service
             └─1267 /usr/libexec/switcheroo-control
```

And I believe the default opengl render is already set to my nvidia.

```
$ glxinfo | grep "OpenGL renderer"
OpenGL renderer string: NV117
```

When I run `glxgears` and/or go to a `webgl` website,  the nvidia gpu is active.

My question is:  **does it mean that** the default gnome windows manager / compositor, ***mutter*, uses my nvidia gpu whenever it can?**  If not, is there a way to force mutter to use nvidia?

Thanks in advance

Comment: prime-select uses nvidia proprietary driver.   For one reason or another I never managed to get proprietary driver to work.    My question is a bit more open-source nvidia driver specific (hence the title contains the word "nouveau").   

I probably will give the proprietary driver a try some time once I regained my patience (I spend days on proprietary driver with no avail as it was my first choice on both 18.04 and 20.04).    it is outside the scope of this question.

Comment: Ohh trust me,  I've done all that everything you can think of before I gave up on it (including trying to manually upgrade the kernel to 5.8.x).   The closest thing I got was to have gdm3 log in displayed.  As soon as I typed password,  the GUI simply freezed.  I have to use prim-select to select intel and reboot to get my GUI back, which defeat the purpose.  

With nouveau,  at least I can log in  and at least gxgears  and webgl actually uses the gpu with freeze the entire GUI.

Comment: No.  I am using X, as shown in my original question as inxi -G output.   I probably will try to get nvidia proprietary driver to work and ask meaningful question then.  But for now,  I am hoping someone can help me with the nouveau setup.   This shouldn't be an obscure question, as there nvidia is very popular and gnome desktop's performance really suffers when a high resolution external monitor is attached.  Hence, the need for performance gain for regular desktop use is real.

Comment: You're right, I missed the X part.  I removed my other comments since they were meaningless.  I hope someone knows enough about Mutter if it can be configured to use a specific GPU. One other thing, if you are running Ubuntu 20.04, please consider going to Ubuntu 18.04.  I had 20.04 installed on my system but it was way to buggy even after a clean install.  Things would just stop working for no reason like repositories, etc that all work just fine in 18.04.

Comment: I upgraded to 20.04 for a false reason:  I spend a lot of time in mainland China (prior to the pandemic) and I really want to use wireguard VPN.   It's after I upgraded to 20.04 I discover that the default 20.04 has not moved to 5.6.x kernel thus wireguard is not supported... yet.

By the way,  I never managed to get nvidia proprietary driver to work in my 18.04 neither.  It had a nasty problem of random freeze, which entire computer would grind to a halt in such that not even control-alt-delete would work, hence, I can't get log files to ask meaningful questions.